# Converted to ARC App crashes on any method iPhone

Tags: iphone, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I converted my app to ARC and removed all the pre-build release errors. It launches, but will crash (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) as soon as I call any method (all of which are attached to UIButtons). I also noticed that it will ask if the user will allow for the app to use the user's location, but the alert will disappear before the user can answer yes or no.

I feel like there's some very basic setting I'm missing causing this.

Here's the first method called, it won't let the user actually say if they'll allow location services. The alert fires then disappears. Does this help anyone's diagnosis?

```
-(void)startLocation
    {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

Also, here's my didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] init];
    StartPageViewController *start = [[StartPageViewController alloc]init];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    if (!context) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }

    start.managedObjectContext = context;
    nav.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:start, nil];

    [_window addSubview:[nav view]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;

}
```

Comment: Have you refactored your code to ARC (Edit->Refactor->Convert to objectice C ARC) ?

Comment: Are the UIButtons hooked up as outlets?  If so, you want the format in your header of `@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;` and everything should be fine

Comment: Still getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS and I still can't tell the app it can use location services. It disappears before I can answer.

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and stepped from there?  That will at least give you a hint as to where it's crashing and you can examine the call stack.

Comment: It hits the break point at didFinishLaunching fine. The first method called on the first view is to start location services. Here's the code for that

Comment: This has been answered but for further readers: After (Edit->Refactor->Convert to objective C ARC) and fixing all possible issues for that to happen, at one point in my game there was `autorelease` block with this line `__IMPL_ARCMT_REMOVED_EXPR__pool`, so being smart i deleted whole line and app was crashing at some other place. When i put block at his place without that strange command everything is back as usual. Check if you have by accident removed something you should not have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed to change (so far) was:

```
 self.window.rootViewController = nav;
```

instead of:

```
[_window addSubview:[nav view]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try retaining your navigation controller by making it a strong property on your delegate.

At the moment, I don't see any code that would cause ARC not to release `nav` at the end of the method. That would release `start`, which would release `context`.

Comment: This just gives me a white screen

Comment: @Terry it looks like the _window ivar would retain at least the `nav`'s view, but maybe not the nav

Comment: All I needed to change (so far) was:

     self.window.rootViewController = nav;

instead of:

    [_window addSubview:[nav view]];

Comment: 'self.window.rootViewController = nav' will also retain `nav`.

Comment: @jbrennan I don't think a controller's view knows anything about the controller, so there wouldn't be a retain there.